# The Information Age and Industrial Revolution "were similar" or "are similar"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-vs-present

The reason why I ask this is because of two reasons:

1. I first thought that things that occur in the past generally have to be described with past tense verbs.
2. Then I thought: "By using past tense, doesn't it imply that the similarity is no longer true, even though it may very well still be true?"

Please help. This has been nagging my brain for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

**are similar**. 
Because one is ongoing, "are" should be used. 
Saying "were" would imply the latter one is also in the past.

Comment: Although I agree with your answer, I don't agree with your justification. It has nothing to do with the fact that one of them is **ongoing**, since I could make the same statement about the classical era and the industrial revolution, neither of which are ongoing. It's a matter of this statement (their similarity) being **currently** correct (= at the time the statement is made), hence the use of present tense.

Comment: If anything, a truth table should reveal to you that _if "are similar" is valid for both ongoing and historical eras, then the ongoing nature does not factor into the validity of "are similar"_.

Comment: Hi @Flater, thanks for the feedback.  I agree with you that regarding two historic eras, we could say "are similar".  However, I do not fully agree that it has nothing to do with the fact that one of them is ongoing.  Thinking about this in terms of a truth table helped me consider this. Where neither are ongoing, both "are" and "were", would be valid ways to compare. In all the other 3 cases, where either one or both epochs are ongoing, then only "are" is valid, IMO. So, e.g. the mesolithic and neolithic can be thought of as similar, in that both, are in the past and, were a long time ago.

Comment: I can give you correct examples of present and past tense, for both ongoing or historical eras. (1) Past tense = the two eras were considered similar in the past, but not currently. (2) Present tense = the two eras are currently considered to be similar. Either of these cases is grammatically valid **regardless** of whether the mentioned eras are ongoing or historical. However, you are correct that for historical eras, the past tense **could** be used in both ways; but that doesn't say anything about the validity of "are similar" (which is **present** tense)